# Does anyone have a plugin that could automatically tag custom post types in wordpress?

Tags: custom-post-types, tags

I was looking at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/web-ninja-auto-tagging-system/ and unfortunately, it wont work on custom post types.

Can anyone suggest (with what changes are needed) to have this work for custom post types?

Comment: on lines 74 & 91 of the plugin it queries the database to get all the posts of type 'post' perhaps if you try with a registered custom post type, it might work. Would need a lot of testing!

Answer (score 2):

For a quick hack.

@ lines 74 and 91 of the plugin its making a SQL request where it's limiting the results to posts only.

```
WHERE post_status='publish' AND post_type='post'
```

So, if you change that to include your custom postypes it should pick them up.

Or simply remove that SQL query and run a standard WP_Query query to return your posts in question.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try it out...if anyone has another plugin to suggest or idea...always much appreciated!

Comment: hey noponies, I tried doing that but nothing changed...maybe I have the wrong custom post type...anyone else have any other ideas?